# How can I find the index of a string, then remove it?

Tags: java

Hello :) I am a junior in high-school and have taken an interest in AP computer science this year. I was able to get in, but unlike others I have not taken the prequisites to the class and I'm not very good at coding. We had an assignment today and the directions were to find the index of a "?" within a string (in the first method), and remove it in the second method. I tried and failed miserably lol, I know that my code isn't correct, how can I correctly write this while following the directions? Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveQuesRunner {

    public void findQuestionMark() {
        String s; 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
        System.out.println("Enter word :: ");
        String.indexOf(?)
    }   

    public void removeQuestionMark() {
        if (findQuestionMark()=true);
            s.replace("?", "");     
    }
}


  public void removeQuestionMark() {

     if (findQuestionMark()=true);
         s.replace("?", "");        
  }
}
```

Comment: good try - what are you doing with `kb`?  Don't foget to read javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Also no `;` at end of `if`

Comment: (1) If you meant `?` to be a character (`char`), it must be in single quote marks.  If you meant it to be a `String`, it must be in double quote marks.  Using it without any quote marks is an error.  (2) The statement that calls `indexOf` must end in a semicolon.  (3) `String.indexOf` returns an `int` that tells you where in the string it is.  But the way you've written it, you're not doing anything with the result.

Comment: hint: your `s` has no value assigned to it -- you can only access `indexOf(...)` through an instance variable such as your `s` -- do not forget quotation mark " " for the argument unless passing a variable of type String.

Comment: (4) You're using `findQuestionMark` as if you're expecting it to have a value.  But it doesn't have a value, because you declared `findQuestionMark` to be `void`.  If you want the value to be "true" or "false", then change the `void` to `boolean` and make the method return true or false.  (5) If you want to compare the result to `true`, you need to use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: (6) `s.replace("?","")` doesn't actually change `s`.  It returns a new string with the changes.  If you want to change `s`, you therefore have to assign the result to `s`, i.e. `s = s.replace(...)`.  This is a _very_ common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not the full code, as I want you to try some more.

```
public int findQuestionMark()

String s = kb.nextLine ();

int index = s.indexOf ('?');

return index;

...

public void removeQuestionMark(int index, String s)

if (findQuestionMark() != -1) {
   return s.replace ("?", "");
}
return ("No ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit some part of the code

```
public class Test {

    public static String result;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        findQuestionMark();

        removeQuestionMark();

    }


    public static String findQuestionMark() {

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter word: ");
          result = input.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Index of ?: " + result.indexOf("?"));
          return result;

    } 

    public static void removeQuestionMark() {
         result = result.replace("?", "");

         System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveQuesRunner
{
String s = ""; 

public int findQuestionMark()
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter word :: ");
s=kb.next();
return s.indexOf("?");
}   

public void removeQuestionMark(int index)
{
if(index >= 0)
  {
    StringBuilder bulid = new StringBuilder(str);
    bulid.deleteCharAt(index);
    str = bulid.toString();
  }    
}
```

Comment: i assume you know enough that how to use a class in your main program lolz